# How to redirect example.com and example.com/anything to example.com/blog

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I want to redirect example.com and example.com/anything to example.com/blog. Please note few things.

I refer example.com for a 1 domain.

I use apache as web server.

My document root is set to /var/www/html/public within apache vhost conf file (For a laravel APP).

I tried setting redirects in .htaccess and using apache vhost conf file and I get redirect too many times error.

Can someone help me to accomplish this please?

Comment: Can you share your current `.htaccess` so others know what you have tried and give you suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for: rewriting on the level of the http server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?anything/?$ /blog [R=301]
```

If by "anything" you actually mean *anything* so that a redirection should get applied regardless of the requested path, then this should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog
RewriteRule ^ /blog [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But unfortunately did not work for me. It creates a redirect loop after redirecting to example.com/blog. Any idea why this is causing?

Comment: The given rule set certainly does _not_ result in a redirection loop by itself, that is exactly what the `RewriteCond` is for. If that does not work for you (did you tripple check that you are _not_ looking at a cached result?), then some other factor must be pesent you did not tell us about. Or you simply accidentally altered the lines I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your routes

```
// web.php
Route::redirect('/', '/blog');
Route::redirect('/anything', '/blog');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your answer. But I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying the APP, within vhost conf file or .htaccess.

Comment: Ok no problem, you tagged laravel, so I offered laravel solution)) good luck

Comment: Thanks. Someone will find your answer very usefull.